# How to invalidate NSTimers before app terminates?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm aware that applicationWillTerminate and applicationDidEnterBackground are appropriate functions to invalidate NSTimers. The problem however is that I opted out of multitasking (set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in plist file) so these functions aren't being called.

Invalidating timers in applicationWillResignActive will prevent me to fire alarms when device is switched to locked (that's the whole point of setting UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES) but that seems to be the only function that is called before the App terminates but unfortunately it's also called when the device is locked so there seems to be a conflict here.

What's the best approach to solving this problem?

Comment: You don't need to invalidate the timers. Your app is going to terminate anyway so the timers will get cleaned up

Comment: Then why is it that the NSTimer only works when the device is turned on and if the device is locked then it only works when it's "busy" such as it is connected to a laptop or is giving away hotspot? I thought that settings UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES was supposed to make my NSTimer work as long as the app is in the foreground mode...

Comment: That is unrelated to your question, however the behaviour you described is an undocumented one that has been observed. It isn't guaranteed to always work that way. Apple makes changes to improve battery life all the time.